# Multiple Doctrine implementation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4, doctrine-odm

I'm using Symfony4 and Doctrine and I'd like to make my app "compatible" with both ODM and ORM.

For that I changed my Documents (my app was originally ODM only) into "generic models" (move from `App\Model\Documents` to `App\Model\Persistence`) and I try using XML Mapping.

I changed in the `doctrine.yaml` and `doctrine_mongodb.yaml` config files the mapping option to `xml`.

From examples like FosUserBundle and [this link](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/doctrine/mapping_model_classes.html) (that's not for symfony4 but I didn't find any similar page for symfony4), I made this in my `Kernel`

```
/**
 * @param \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder $container
 */
protected function build(ContainerBuilder $container): void
{

    $mappingsODM = array(
        realpath(__DIR__.'/Model/Mapping/ODM') => 'App\Model\Persistence',
        realpath(__DIR__.'/Model/Mapping/ODM/Files') => 'App\Model\Persistence\Files',
    );
    $mappingsORM = array(
        realpath(__DIR__.'/Model/Mapping/ORM') => 'App\Model\Persistence',
        realpath(__DIR__.'/Model/Mapping/ORM/Files') => 'App\Model\Persistence\Files',
    );

    if (class_exists('Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\DoctrineOrmMappingsPass')) {
        $container->addCompilerPass(DoctrineOrmMappingsPass::createXmlMappingDriver($mappingsORM, [], 'app.backend_type_orm'));
    }

    if (class_exists('Doctrine\Bundle\MongoDBBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\DoctrineMongoDBMappingsPass')) {
        $container->addCompilerPass(DoctrineMongoDBMappingsPass::createXmlMappingDriver($mappingsODM, [], 'app.backend_type_mongodb'));
    }
    //this CompilerPass is here to add my Repositories (ODM or ORM) in the ServiceContainer depending a param.
    //$container->addCompilerPass(new DoctrineRepositoryCompilerPass());
}
```

With this, I have the following Exception message

```
No mapping file found named 'Chapter.mongodb.xml' for class 'App\Model\Persistence\Chapter'.
```

The FQCN is good, I have my mappings file in `src/Model/Mapping/ODM` directory (I only set up ODM for now).

Like you saw, in the `$mappingsODM` I set my mapping folder => namespace but then, when I load my Repository I have the following dump in the `$driver` variable (in MetadataFactory)

```
"FOS\UserBundle\Model" => XmlDriver {#59 ▼
    #locator: SymfonyFileLocator {#58 ▼
      #paths: array:1 [▼
        0 => "/var/www/html/rapp/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Resources/config/doctrine-mapping"
      ]
      #prefixes: array:1 [▼
        "/var/www/html/rapp/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Resources/config/doctrine-mapping" => "FOS\UserBundle\Model"
      ]
      #fileExtension: ".mongodb.xml"
      -nsSeparator: "."
    }
    #classCache: null
    #globalBasename: null
  }
  "App\Model\Persistence" => XmlDriver {#61 ▼
    #locator: SymfonyFileLocator {#60 ▼
      #paths: array:2 [▼
        0 => "/var/www/html/rapp/src/Model/Mapping/ODM"
        1 => "/var/www/html/rapp/src/Model/Mapping/ODM/Files"
      ]
      #prefixes: array:2 [▼
        "/var/www/html/rapp/src/Model/Mapping/ODM" => "App\Model\Persistence"
        "/var/www/html/rapp/src/Model/Mapping/ODM/Files" => "App\Model\Persistence\Files"
      ]
      #fileExtension: ".mongodb.xml"
      -nsSeparator: "."
    }
    #classCache: null
    #globalBasename: null
  }
```

I don't really see any differences between the FosUserBundle part and mine (except the folder path, of course, but they are good)

I do regularly `php bin/console doctrine:mongodb:cache:clear-metadata` to see if there is a messed up cache but nothing change.

Here is one of my xml mapping file as exemple

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doctrine-mongo-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/odm/doctrine-mongo-mapping"
                        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                        xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/odm/doctrine-mongo-mapping
                http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/odm/doctrine-mongo-mapping.xsd">
    <document name="App\Model\Persistence\Chapter" repository-class="App\Model\ODM\Repository\ChapterRepository">

        .... my fields

    </document>

</doctrine-mongo-mapping>
```

Am I missing something ? some `Kernel` or `CompilerPass` I missed ?

Edit :

In the `SymfonyFileLocator:findMappingFile()` method, here is my `$this->paths` dump:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => "/var/www/html/rapp/src/Model/Persistence"
]
```

It's not my mapping folder, But my ModelClass folder. so the mapping files `*.mongodb.xml` are not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel dumb after fixed that myself ...

It was the `dir` options in `doctrine.mongodb.yaml` config. It was set to my Class folder while it's supposed to be the mapping folder.

With annotation that was good, since the mapping is inside the classes, but with XML it's wrong.

So I don't really know what's the meaning of passing the mapping path in the `DoctrineMongoDBMappingsPass::createXmlMappingDriver()` methods (in the first parameter `$arguments`) but it seems the `dir` options is used instead.

Edit : I'll mark this answer as Accepted as soon as I can.